# How to store cookie for diffrent domain

Tags: angular, http, cookies

How to store the cookie for the different domains in angular? I am using package `ngx-cookie-service` But when I am giving parameters for the different domains it's not storing.

This is my code?

```
this.cookieService.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${res.access}`, 1 , '/', '172.61.25.20', false, "Lax" );
```

How can I solve this issue. Any suggestions of great help!!

Comment: You can't create, edit or delete cookies for other domains, since that would be a huge security issue. IIRC (not sure, so don't take my word for it) you can manipulate the cookies of the subdomain (e.g. if you're on www.example.com you can delete cookies  for www.sub.example.com). Note that if this works, it won't work the other way around (e.g. if you're on www.sub.example.com, you can manipulate cookies here, but can't manipulate the cookies for www.example.com).

Comment: @TotallyNewb That the only way I have left to fix this problem i believe